# Java Inheritance: Child class not executing

Tags: java

I was practicing inheritance in Java, and faced the following issue:

Code for parent class:

```java
public class FEB7 {
    String address,name;
    void get(String n, String a){
        name = n;
        address = a;
    }

    void show(){
        System.out.println("name is "+name);
        System.out.println("address is " + address);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // compile time poly is method overloading, we will look at runtime poly
        FEB7 obj = new FEB7();
        obj.get("name1","address1");
        obj.show();
    } 
}
```

Code for child class:

```java
public class FEB8 extends FEB7 {
    String regno;

    void get(String r) {
        regno = r;
    }

    void showreg() {
        System.out.println("regno is " + regno);
    }

    public static void main(String args) {
        FEB8 obj1 = new FEB8();
        obj1.get("name2", "address2");
        obj1.get("regno1");
        obj1.show();
        obj1.showreg();
    }
}
```

Both are separate .java files. When I try to execute the parent class file, it works, but for some reason I cannot even run the child class. The following message is there:

> The file FEB8.java is not executable. please select a main class you
> want to run

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `main` method in `FEB8` has `String args` as the argument instead of `String args[]`. Change it to `args[]` and try again.